# Vuetify data table is not showing data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Vuetify data table is not showing data, it shows that there are 1 row out of 1 displayed, but the table body is empty. My component code:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
  >
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Users',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          fat: 6.0,
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped  lang="stylus">
</style>
```

Result:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you're using Vuetify 1.x You should add a template with scoped slot :

```
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
  >
  <template v-slot:items="props">

      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>

    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

or you should upgrade to the version 2.0 which does simply :

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>
```

if you want to customize your data cells check this ***[`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57945017/8172857)***

Comment: Yeah, was looking at the documentation for version 2.0.0, you don't have to add template there. But I have 1.5.16 installed...

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution but it didn't work.. My Vue version is 2.5.16
Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944894/how-to-format-vuetify-data-table-date-column/57945017#57945017) ,i this doesn't work post a detailed question and give the link

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I had put `headers` array in the `props` section instead of `data`. So even when `v-datatable` had its `items` property set to an array of objects (which can be confirmed using Vue Dev Tools; a Chrome extension), it would not show any rows.

I spent half an hour banging my head, only to finally realize this problem. As soon as I moved `headers` from `props` to `data`, the table started showing rows. Hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: please clarify more your issue and the solution