# How to format Vuetify data table date column?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a simple data table using *Vuetify* data table. One of the column is a `createdOn` (date time), I want to format it. How can I do it ?

This is what i get now:

[image: This is what i get now]

```
<template>
   <v-layout>
      <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="logs">
      </v-data-table>
   <v-layout>
</template>
<script>
      headers: [
        { text: "Time", value: "createdOn", dataType: "Date" },
        { text: "Event Source", value: "eventSourceName" },
        { text: "Event Details", value: "eventDetails" },
        { text: "User", value: "user" }
      ],
      items: [],
</script>
```

Comment: how do you want to format it?

Comment: hi @Boussadjra Brahim I get "2019-09-14T17:03:24.3949548" format now. I want to make it "2019-09-14 3:24 AM". Is there a way to do it like pipes in angular?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You should use a [`custom row cell`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#customizing-default-rows) :

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="logs">
  <template v-slot:item.createdOn="{ item }">
    <span>{{ new Date(item.createdOn).toLocaleString() }}</span>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: You may have a typo, I needed to use singular item.createdOn as the v-slot attribute, plural items.createdOn did not work.

Comment: For me there is an issue: If I pass '2020-07-01' it gets rendered as  "1.7.2020, 02:00:00", which is most often not what you want. Javascript takes the given value as UTC and displays it with the  offset of the user.

Comment: @MathiasF i think the problem is with your locale, i answered the question with the given input `2019-09-14T17...` i recommend to ask a new question with more details

Comment: This answer could be updated to avoid the "'v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier" error by changing `<template v-slot:item.createdOn="{ item }">` to `<template v-slot:[\`item.createdOn\`]="{ item }">`. See ['v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63309643/991138).

Comment: thank you for your comment, it could be updated to what?

Comment: To `<template v-slot:[\`item.createdOn\`]="{ item }">`.

Comment: That called a dynamic slot, for example you could do `v-slot:[someprop]="{}"` knowing that `someprop` is a property defined in script or template that represent a string of a valid slot

Comment: for some reason you want a dynamic timestamp based on a condition returned from a computed property `myTimestamp(){return this.updated?'updatedOn':'createdOn'}` then in template you could do `v-slot:[myTimestamp]="{item}"`

Answer (score 21):

I found out a way to format cell values using dynamic slot names and a function in the header object:

In the `<v-data-table>` I did:

```html
<template v-for="header in headers.filter((header) => header.hasOwnProperty('formatter'))" v-slot:[`item.${header.value}`]="{ header, value }">
  {{ header.formatter(value) }}
</template>
```

and in the vue `data` property I did:

```js
headers: [
  // ...
  { text: 'Value for example', value: '10000', formatter: formatCurrency },
  // ...
]
```

And finally in the `methods` prop I did:

```js
formatCurrency (value) {
  return "$ " + (value / 100).toFixed(2);
}
```

Here's a sandbox to see it in action:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-datatable-value-formatter-jdtxj?file=/src/App.vue

###### EDIT:

In this specific case you could use `momentjs` or javascript's `Date()`. I've added a momentjs example to the codesandbox.

Comment: Yes - great work @SneakyLenny!  Saved me like 2 hrs.

Got this to work for a more generic "customize every column" approach:

`
<template
                      v-for="header in headers"
                      v-slot:[``item.${header.value}``]="{ header, value }"
                    >
                      {{ formatCell(value) }}
                    </template>
`

Comment: can use still sort/filter on date columns irrespective of chosen format after that? i.e. does the table use the underlying Dates or the newly formatted strings for its internal sorting/filtering algorithm after that?

Comment: @niko Sorting is based on the data given, otherwise you could have formatted the data beforehand. Example: if the data would be 4 - 2 - 1 - 3 and a formatter would add random letters to the format the display is sorted as y1 - x2 - u3 - a4. If that makes sense.

Comment: This is also useful to create <template> based on the data dynamically, say if you have "dynamic headers", then you can inspect the headers and create templates. Very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an even simpler solution or at least one where you can format other columns as well:

```js
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="logs">
  <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in items" :key="logs.id">
        <td> {{ new Date(item.createdOn).toLocaleString() }} </td>
        ...
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

The trick is using the `body` slot of `v-data-table`. More information [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#slots).

Answer (score 0):

I have also used global filter with v-slot:

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="logs">
  <template v-slot:item.createdOn="{ item }">
    <span>{{ item.createdOn | myGlobalDateFilter }}</span>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In datatable component Datatable.vue

```
<template v-for="slot in slots" v-slot:[`item.${slot.slotName}`]="{ item }">
  <slot :name="slot.slotName" :variable="item"></slot>
</template>

export default {
props:
slots:{
  type:Array,
  default:null
},
```

and parent component

```
<Datatable
 :headers="headers"
  :items="stokhareketleri"
  :title="title"
  :slots="slots">
<template v-slot:column_name="{ variable }">
  <v-chip
        color="green"
        dark
      >
      {{variable.column_name}}
      </v-chip>
</template>
  </Datatable>


data () {
      return {
        slots:[{ 
          Id: 1, slotName: 'column_name'
          }],
```