# How to alter a value in a v-data-table

Tags: vuetify.js

I am new to vuetify and I'm trying to take the value in a column of a v-data-table and convert it to it's text equivalent, but can't find out how to do it.

```
headers: [
    { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
    { text: 'Type', value: 'typeName(type)' },
  ]
```

I have tried typeName as a computed value and as a method:

```
typeName(typId) {
  return ...
},
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Do you want a dynamic headers or dynamic column value of type?

Comment: I want to change the value.  If I just do `type` instead of `typeName(type)`, I get the number.  I want to change it to its matching text value.

Comment: Colume name is type, but the value you wanted to be a formatted value of type, Am I right here?

Comment: Yes, you could say it that way.  The actual value comes from a database endpoint, so I can't change it at source.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57945017/209288

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can format the column value by adding a explict function

Here is the working codepen which reverse the value of first column: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/GRRjaqj?editors=1010

> If you have headers type, no need to call the function from here,
>   instead we need to call from column by adding a template

```
headers: [
    { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
    { text: 'Type', value: 'type' },
  ]
```

> In the HTML , add a template with slot points to body

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"   >
<template v-slot:body="{items}">
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.name">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{typeName(item.type)}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

> Inside data property add a property typeName

```
data() {
  return {
    typeName: (type) => type.substring(2),
  }
}
```