# Change Vuetify format date in <td> to spesific format

Tags: date, datetime, vue.js, format, vuetify.js

i have json return value, like this :

"registration_date": "2015-08-31T17:00:00.000Z",

and in this is the code i already tried based on this (stackoverflow) link :

[How to format Vuetify data table date column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944894/how-to-format-vuetify-data-table-date-column)

```
<td class="text-left">{{ new Date(form.registration_date).toLocaleDateString() }}</td>
```

but it gives me 'Invalid Date' on the screen,

i want to make the date format like this : 31/08/2015 17:00:00

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use https://momentjs.com/

```
moment(form.registration_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss')
```

To use the moment.js

npm install moment --save

after installing import it to the vue file that want to integrate.

like this: 
import moment from 'moment'

Comment: thank you, i use moment as you suggest, 

now the date showed as the format

but why the date become different ?

from this : 2015-08-31T17:00:00.000Z 

become  01/09/2015 12:00:00 

did you know ?