# How to format Vuetify data table Float column to decimal and pt-br?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a simple data table using Vuetify data table. One of the column is a float type, I want to BRL format. How can I do it ?

[image]

I want: 176,000 - 300,000 - 2,017.363 - 5,043.407 - 637,168 ...

```
<template>
   <data-tables
            v-loading="listLoading"
            :data="data"
            :filters="filters"
            :total="totalRows"
            :pagination-props="pageSizes"
            :current-page.sync="currentPage"
            :page-size="pageSize"
            @expand-change="handleExpand"
            @query-change="list"
            @selection-change="handleSelectionChange"
            @size-change="handleSizeChange"
          >
</template>

 methods: {
        loadColumns() {
          var columns = [
            { prop: '', label: '', resizable: true, align: 'left', headerAlign: 'center', width: '15' },
            { prop: '', label: '', resizable: true, align: 'left', headerAlign: 'left', width: '30' },
            { prop: '', label: '', resizable: true, align: 'left', headerAlign: 'left', width: '40' },
            { prop: 'Value', label: 'Value', resizable: true, align: 'left', headerAlign: 'left', width: '50' },

          ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format Vuetify data table date column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944894/how-to-format-vuetify-data-table-date-column)

Comment: How can I use this solution to format to decimal value?

Comment: The solution is about replacing Vuetify's default cell rendering logic with your own. There is no way how to tell Vuetify data type (formating) of your value. You must format the value yourself. If you don't know how, use search (`JavaScript format number`)

Comment: Alright, thank you for help. This really help ;DD