# JSON data not displaying in Vuetify v-data-table using Axios

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuetify.js, airtable

Can't get the JSON data to display.  I'm receiving the data.  Trying to take two of the fields from the JSON and put it in a v-data-table.  In it's current form, the table generates and the correct # of rows appears for the # of records, but each row is blank.

An example of the JSON data:

```
"records": [{
    "id": "recFWwl9WYekKQhy5",
    "fields": {
        "Date": "2020-03-28T04:35:00.000Z",
        "Client": [
            "reciiW7xvFNJNb4yF"
        ],
        "Details": "Testing",
        "Town": "madfa"
    },
    "createdTime": "2020-03-25T04:35:16.000Z"
  }]
}
```

And the code:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:item="props">
        <tr>
            <td>{{new Date(props.item.Date).toLocaleString()}}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.Client }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.Details }}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  components: {},
  computed: {},
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Date',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: true,
          value: 'Date',
        },
        { text: 'Client Name', value: 'Client' },
        { text: 'Details', value: 'Details' },
      ],
      items: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.loadItems(); 
  },
  methods: {
    loadItems() {

      // Init variables
      var self = this
      var app_id = "appID";
      var app_key = "key";
      this.items = []
      axios.get(
        "https://api.airtable.com/v0/"+app_id+"/openrideAppointments",
        { 
          headers: { Authorization: "Bearer "+app_key } 
        }
      ).then(function(response){
        self.items = response.data.records.map((item)=>{
          return {
              id: item.id,
              ...item.fields
          }
        })
      }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: which vuetify version are you using ?

Comment: try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944894/how-to-format-vuetify-data-table-date-column/57945017#57945017) if you're using vuetify v2

Comment: I'm using Vuetify 2 - trying your answer now

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm now getting the date in a nice pretty format going into the appropriate Date column, however I'm still trying to figure out how to add the Client and Details values into their appropriate columns (or displaying at all).:

Comment: You guys are both awesome - updated with final solution.

Comment: you **should not** update your question with solution, try to keep the original question and post the solution as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Airtable API response has the values inside `fields`, so you should flatten the response...

```
 self.items = response.data.records.map((item)=>{
        return {
            id: item.id,
            ...item.fields
        }
 })
```

And make sure you're using the correct Vuetify 2.x slot template...

```
    <template v-slot:item="props">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ props.item.Date }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.Client }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.Details }}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/gdv5OfRlOL

Comment: Thank you, however, I added the fields and its still not working.

Comment: this will not work since that  vuetify v1.x syntax, however he's using v2 so he should do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944894/how-to-format-vuetify-data-table-date-column/57945017#57945017)

Comment: This works!  Boussadjra's answer also works with date formatting (though I haven't yet figured it out completely).  Thank you!

Comment: You guys are both awesome - updated with final solution.

Comment: @gcubed you **should not** update your question with solution, try to keep the original question and post the solution as answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944894/how-to-format-vuetify-data-table-date-column/57945017#57945017) which formats one column, but if you want to format multiple columns you should do something like :

```
 <template v-slot:item="props">
        <tr>
            <td>{{new Date(props.item.fields.Date).toLocaleString()}}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.fields.Client }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.fields.Details }}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
```