# 'v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, eslint

I am using Vuetify's datatable, we have different slots with some props for example below

```html
<template #header.data-table-select="{ on, props }">
   <v-simple-checkbox color="purple" v-bind="props" v-on="on"></v-simple-checkbox>
</template>
```

I am also using Vue's eslint plugin to check for any errors/bad code / or any violation, but if I use the above code snippet in my file it gives me the error

```
'v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier
```

as per this [doc](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/valid-v-slot.html), it is right.

but it doesn't have any example of how we should handle this case.

how can I remove this warning/or fix it correctly, without making it an exemption.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

I don't see any `v-slot` in the code you provided so I can show you only my usecase.

With Eslint error:

```html
<template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
```

Without error:

```html
<template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
```

Comment: My code formatter is not liking this workaround, its converting it to this
`<template v-slot:[&#x60;item.actions&#x60;]="{ item }">`
any ideas?

Comment: @DiegoGarcia Backtiks come with  ECMAScript 6 so you stack most probably does use ES5. You could update your stack to be able to handle ES6 or give single quotes a try.

Comment: @Hexodus I am using ES6 and same problem as DiegoGarcia

Comment: @ChrisHerbst Well there seems to some difference between our tools or stacks. I'm using vscode and latest 2.x Vue with 3.x Cli by the way.

Comment: @DiegoGarcia add `"parser": "vue"` to your `.prettierrc` file or `--parser vue` to your command

Comment: @Hexodus, the '#' is a Vue shortcut for 'v-slot:'

Comment: for anyone who was looking for the shorthand notation in the docs like me: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots-Shorthand

Comment: @DiegoGarcia you are probably using Vetur, you can change vetur html formatter from it's settings. Change it from prettyhtml to prettier.

Comment: For me worked only with item without curly brackets:

`<template v-slot:[`footer.page-text`]="item">
  {{ item.pageStart }} - {{ item.pageStop }}
  {{ $t("dataTable.of") }} {{ item.itemsLength }}
</template>`

Comment: v-slot:item.name="props"  What about this? i have the same error with it

Comment: I did not know you could do this! We have these warnings on several pages and this makes my OCD just a little bit happier.

Comment: Does anybody know why we should use backticks in that case instead of quotes?

Comment: Even though this works, explicitly allowing modifiers in the eslint config, as described in @nokazn's answer, feels cleaner to me.

Comment: What should I do with typescript? If I use this solution it will produce a TS 2538 error, since I can't simply use strings as array indexes

It says "Type 'string[]' cannot be used as an index type" and won't compile

Answer (score 63):

In `eslint-plugin-vue@^7.1.0`, you can use `allowModifiers` option in `vue/valid-v-slot` rule.

```js
// .eslintrc.js
'vue/valid-v-slot': ['error', {
  allowModifiers: true,
}],
```

[vue/valid-v-slot #options](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/valid-v-slot.html#options)

Comment: Or if you have a javascript formatted file (.eslintrc.js) like me you can add:
    rules: {
        'vue/valid-v-slot': [
          'error',
          {
            allowModifiers: true,
          },
        ],
      },

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with my setup, nuxtjs, vscode...

Comment: It seems that when Vetur is installed, the rule cannot be disabled in .eslintrc. It seems that the answer by Daniel Schmidt is the solution.

Answer (score 24):

For me the following Entry in settings.json fixed the problem:

```
 "vetur.validation.template": false
```

Comment: This also worked for me. Apparently this error originates from Vetur whose built-in `eslint-plugin-vue` does not reference a projects `.eslintrc` . (taken from https://gitmemory.com/issue/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/1269/668921391)

Comment: Adding this line to the .vscode/settings.json in my project root didn't work.  To get this to work, I had to go to File --> Preferences --> Extensions, select the Vetur extension, click on it's settings, scroll down to find "Edit in settings.json" and add the line to the bottom of that file.  That's a different file for whatever reason, so it worked when I added it there.

Comment: Are you sure that doing so will not disable anything else beside of that?

Answer (score 18):

I tried Hexodus' answer, but the template wasn't rendering at all in my case.

I got it to work perfectly with this, without any eslint rule modification:

```html
<template #[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
```

Answer (score 17):

**EDIT:** As notified by the comments and Hexodus' (correct) answer, you can work around the linting warning by using dynamic slot names that return a string(template). 'Not enabling' is no longer recommended, as this is now a standard rule. Thus, I recommend using [Hexodus' method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63309643/3739756) over disabling the valid v-slot rule altogether.

---

**Original Post:**

You can't really fix this linting warning.

- Vue syntax for modifiers use the dot to alter the way a
  directive functions (e.g. v-model.number)
- The way Vuetify dynamically names their slots uses a dot in order to
  select a specific part of the component (#header.data-table-select).

ESLint can't distinguish whether you're trying to set a modifier on a slot (which is impossible), or if you have a slot name that contains a dot.

The easiest thing you can do is disable the rule. Since the 'valid-v-slot' rule isn't enabled by default by any of the base configurations of eslint-plugin-vue, you should be able to find it under "rules" in your eslint config.

Comment: I disagree. As the answer from @Hexodus shows, this problem can be solved.

Comment: Looks like this is now enabled by default FYI

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```html
<template v-slot:item.createdDate="{ item }">
```

if you use the format *vetur*, add this option in vscode settings:

```
"vetur.validation.template": false
```

Comment: Works for Neovim too!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this isn't the answer, and you also may not buy into my solution but this is what I did.

ANS: I downgraded Vetur to version 0.23! It worked! (Waiting a new version release that addresses the issue.

Open the Extensions side panel on VSCode, right click Vetur and select `install other versions`.

Alternatively, if your code is working fine, a line before the `vue-eslint-plugin` error you can try `<!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-v-html -->` to disable eslint for next line or `<!-- eslint-disable -->` to disable every disable linting below it.

Worked for some people but not for me and may not work for you. Either way, prefer Vetur downgrade

I am using laravel framework, and vuetify. Previous codes suddenly reported eslint errors with red lines - vue/valid-v-slot directive, adding multiple root nodes to the template, and so on without recommending any quick fix, yet they are all working fine. Answers I got from search never yielded any result till I downgraded, any other solution will be so welcomed!

Comment: `<!-- eslint-disable-next-line -->` is what did it for me.

Comment: Can't believe I came back searching for my own answer

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me:

in .vue

```
<template v-slot:[getitemcontrols()]="props">
```

in .js

```
 methods: {
    getitemcontrols() {
      return `item.controls`;
    },
```

Comment: you should use `computed` in this case.  
That would be a good solution when dealing with deep-nested values (for instance `item.controls.user.devReports.ReportBug`)

Answer (score 3):

You can define the dynamic slot name as follows:

```
<template #[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
// your code
</template>
```

You can find more information in the official Vue documentation:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#dynamic-slot-names

Answer (score 2):

For me this config added to package.json worked

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/base"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  }
```