# ESLint VueJS v-slot

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, eslint, v-slot

I got an issue with Eslint using modifiers in v-slot

I've try to follow the answer by nokazn in this question :
['v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344980/v-slot-directive-doesnt-support-any-modifier)
And the documentation of lint for vuejs
https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/valid-v-slot.html

I add in my `.eslintrc.js` file :

```
'vue/valid-v-slot': ['error', {
  allowModifiers: true,
}],
```

But i got the following error in the validation of the lint file :

```
Configuration for rule "vue/valid-v-slot" is invalid:
    Value [{"allowModifiers":true}] should NOT have more than 0 items.
```

What I try to get accepted by lint is the following code :

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="data"
        disable-pagination
        fixed-header
      >
        <template v-slot:item.EDIT>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
```

(note that this code is working beside the lint error)

Comment: Are you using the latest ESLint plugin? `allowModifiers` was added in 7.1.0. https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/releases/tag/v7.1.0

Comment: Yes i do, from my package.json :
    "eslint": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.1.0",

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344980/v-slot-directive-doesnt-support-any-modifier)

Comment: No it does not sorry,  my question is how to write that esLint line, not how to rewrite my code

Answer (score 8):

Same issue here:
use `"vue/valid-v-slot": "off"` work for me!

```
<template  v-slot:[`item.monto`]='{ item }'>
          ${{ formatCLP(item.monto) }}
        </template>
```