# @click:row not triggered in v-data-table (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have a v-data-table from vuetify where I have two click-events. One is triggered (deleteBooking), the other not (booking_clicked)?! The button is to delete an item. The row-click event is to show the user additional information for the clicked row.

```
<v-data-table
    item-key="id"
    v-model="selected_bookings"
    :loading="isLoading"
    :items="tmp_bookings"
    :headers="headers"
    :single-select="single_select"
    :hide-default-footer="true"
    @click:row="booking_clicked"
    :footer-props="{
        'items-per-page-options': [-1]
    }"
    class="elevation-1">
        <template slot="item" slot-scope="row">
            <tr>
                <td>{{row.item.booking_text}}</td>
                <td>
                    <v-btn class="mx-2" dark small color="red" @click="deleteBooking(row.item)">
                       <v-icon dark>mdi-delete-forever</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
</v-data-table>

booking_clicked(item){
 console.log(item);
}

deleteBooking(booking_item) {
  console.log(booking_item);
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting up the row click like this:

```js
@click:row="(item) => booking_clicked(item)"
```

### Update

Check this codesanbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70203336-32vby?file=/src/components/DataTableActions.vue

If you want to add an extra column to your `v-data-table` there's no need to use the main `ìtem` slot, unless you want to modify the whole row. If all you want to do is add like example a delete button. You just need to add it to the `headers` array first. On my example I added an extra column for **actions**.

```js
headers: [
   {
      text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
      align: 'start',
      sortable: false,
      value: 'name',
   },
   { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
   { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
   { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
   { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
   { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
   { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions'}
],
```

After that, all you need to do is customize the slot for the actions column, inside your `v-data-table`. Also, to avoid the `@click:row` effect when you click your delete button you need to use `@click.stop` on your delete button.

```html
<v-data-table
   :headers="headers"
   :items="desserts"
   :items-per-page="5"
   class="elevation-1"
   @click:row="(item) => dessertRowlicked(item)"
>
   <template  #item.actions="{ item }">
      <v-icon color="primary" @click.stop="deleteDessert(item)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
   </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: I'll make a codesanbox for you, I think you can also improve the way how you're adding the delete button. There's no need to use the custom item slot.

Comment: It's working. So i marked the answer as accepted answer. But i get now the warning: 'v-slot' directive doesn't support any modifier.

Comment: Yeah, that's a common eslint warning that happens when you use vuetify slots. You can read more about it in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344980/v-slot-directive-doesnt-support-any-modifier) and in this [github](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1165) post. You can fix the warning in several ways, I just simply set `'vue/valid-v-slot': 'off'` in my eslint config file.