# How to change text and color of a column value inside a <v-data-table> based on a condition with Vue.js 2.6.11 and Viutify 2.2.11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm building a web app using ASP.NET CORE as the backend and vue.js as the frontend. Using Vuetify's current CRUD Datatable UI Component (compatible with Vue.js2) for a page called "Category", I've run into the problem of trying to change the Category's "State" column value (as in if the Category is "Active" or "Inactive") based on a condition. This is how the result of the Data Table looks like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       Options       |       Name       |     Description     |      State       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    Edit / Delete    |    Videogames    |  Electronic Device  |       true       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    Edit / Delete    |      Tablets     |  Electronic Device  |       true       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    Edit / Delete    |   Flat Screens   |  Electronic Device  |       false      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    Edit / Delete    |      Laptop      |  Electronic Device  |       true       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

What I would like to achieve is to set a condition where if the Category's State is true, then replace the value as "Active" with a blue text. Else it replaces the value as "Inactive" with red text.

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       Options       |       Name       |     Description     |      State       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    Edit / Delete    |    Videogames    |  Electronic Device  |      Active      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    Edit / Delete    |      Tablets     |  Electronic Device  |      Active      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    Edit / Delete    |   Flat Screens   |  Electronic Device  |     Inactive     |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    Edit / Delete    |      Laptop      |  Electronic Device  |      Active      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

**HTML:**

```
<template>
<v-layout align-start>
    <v-flex>
        <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="categories"
        :search="search"
        sort-by="name"
        class="elevation-1"
        >
        <template v-slot:top>
            <v-toolbar flat color="white">
            <v-toolbar-title>Categories</v-toolbar-title>
            <v-divider
                class="mx-4"
                inset
                vertical
            ></v-divider>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-text-field class="text-xs-center" v-model="search" append-icon="search" label="Search" single-line hide-details></v-text-field>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">New</v-btn>
                </template>
                <v-card>
                <v-card-title>
                    <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
                </v-card-title>

                <v-card-text>
                    <v-container>
                    <v-row>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                        <v-text-field v-model="name" label="Name"></v-text-field>
                        </v-col>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                        <v-text-field v-model="description" label="Description"></v-text-field>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                    </v-container>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
                    <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="guardar">Save</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-dialog>
            </v-toolbar>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:item.options="{ item }">
            <v-icon
            small
            class="mr-2"
            @click="editItem(item)"
            >
            edit
            </v-icon>
            <v-icon
            small
            @click="deleteItem(item)"
            >
            delete
            </v-icon>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:no-data>
            <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize">Reset</v-btn>
        </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data(){
        return{

            categories:[],
            dialog: false,
            headers: [
                { text: 'Options', value: 'options', sortable: false },
                { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
                { text: 'Description', value: 'description', sortable: false },
                { text: 'State', value: 'state', sortable: false },
            ],
            search: '',
            editedIndex: -1,
            id: '',
            name: '',
            description: '',
            valid: 0,
            validMessage: [],
        }
    },

    computed: {
        formTitle () {
        return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Category' : 'Edit Category'
        },
    },

    watch: {
        dialog (val) {
        val || this.close()
        },
    },

    created () {
        this.list();
    },

    methods:{
        list(){
            let me=this;
            axios.get("api/Categories/List").then(function(response){
                me.categories=response.data;
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });

        },

        editItem (item) {
            this.id=item.idcategory;
            this.name=item.name;
            this.description=item.descrition;
            this.editedIndex=1;
            this.dialog = true
        },

        deleteItem (item) {
            const index = this.desserts.indexOf(item)
            confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') && this.desserts.splice(index, 1)
        },

        close () {
            this.dialog = false;
            this.limpiar();
        },

        clean() {
            this.id = "";
            this.name = "";
            this.description = "";
            this.editedIndex = -1;
        },

        guardar () {
            if (this.validate()){
                return;
            }
            if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
                let me=this;
                axios.put('api/Categorias/Edit', {
                    'idcategory': me.id,
                    'name': me.nombre,
                    'description': me.description
                }).then(function(response){
                    me.close();
                    me.list();
                    me.clean();
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                })
            } else {
                let me=this;
                axios.post('api/Categories/Create', {
                    'name': me.name,
                    'description': me.description
                }).then(function(response){
                    me.close();
                    me.list();
                    me.clean();
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        },

        validate () {
            this.valid=0;
            this.validMessage=[];
            if(this.name.length < 3 || this.name.length > 50){
                this.validMessage.push("The name should be in between 3 and 50 characters.")
            }
            if(this.valid.length){
                this.valid=1;
            }
            return this.valid;
        },

    }
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format Vuetify data table date column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944894/how-to-format-vuetify-data-table-date-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `item.state` slot you can achieve this:

```
<template v-slot:item.state="{ item }">
{{item.state? ... : ...}}
</template>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Your solution was simpler than I thought it would be. The only thing I'm still trying to do is change the color of the template tag containing the value based on the condition if it's active or not.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like all you need is a dynamic class on the location where the color changes:

`:class="active? 'text--primary' : 'text--red'"` .

https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/colors

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't do cause I've already applied Varun A's suggestion which worked to change the value as I wanted, but still implementing :class="active? 'text--primary' : 'text--red'" in the same <template> tag won't do the trick. I may be wrong and simply just inserted this code in the wrong place though.