# How to get access to a specific header column in Vuetify data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

How can I get access to a specific header column in Vuetify data-table to customize it? Let's say I would like to hide it by using a css class-name.

In [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#data-tables) suggested to use `header.<name>` to get acess to. But I don't have a clear understanding how to this due to the lack of an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in official [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#customizing-default-header) :

> You can use the dynamic slots `header.<name>` to customize only certain columns. `<name>` is the name of the value property in the corresponding header item sent to headers.

You could do :

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:header.name="{ header }">
      {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }}
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        ...
      ],
    }),
  }
</script>
```

For example `<template v-slot:header.<name>="{ header }">` gives you an access to the correspondant item in `headers` config `{ text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },` where you could use the `text` and the `value` in order to customize them like :

```
<template v-slot:header.name="{ header }">
      <i>{{ header.text.toUpperCase() }}</i>
    </template
```

If you want to customize rows check this ***[`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944894/how-to-format-vuetify-data-table-date-column/57945017#57945017)***