# How can I display image in a vuetify datatable?

Tags: image, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js, v-slot

I am using vuetify table (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#edit-dialog).
I have images stored under - value: "image",

```
  headers: any = [
    {
      text: "Photo",
      value: "image",
    },
    { text: "Character ID", value: "id" },
    { text: "Name", value: "name" },
    { text: "Gender", value: "gender" },
    { text: "Species", value: "species" },
    { text: "Last episode", value: "episode" },
    { text: "Add to favourites", value: "iron" },
  ];
```

so I can display links to images in the Photo column

But can I display these images instead?

Is it possible using v-slot?
Could anyone assist me in it and advise how to do it?

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944894/how-to-format-vuetify-data-table-date-column/57945017#57945017

Comment: in your case you could do `<template v-slot:item.image="{ item }"><img :src="item.image"  alt=""/></template>`