# vue - interpolation html value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

there is a **v-data-table** with server side pagination, where I used a **formatter** for a specific column as described to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65904188).

the need is to replace it with **HTML** and not **plain text**. For example my function is like :

```js
    formatCurrency (value) {
        return '<strong>' + value + '</strong>';
        //'<v-icon dark small>tick-outline</v-icon>' + value;
    },
```

when I using this getting the pure HTML.... as :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html) directive :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      price: 555.33
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formatCurrency (value) {
      return '<strong>' + value + '</strong>';
        //'<v-icon dark small>tick-outline</v-icon>' + value;
    },
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
 <div v-html="formatCurrency(price)"></div> 
</div>
```