# Vuetify Table - Show nicer timestamp format in a column

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have this timestamp format in my UI directly from the API/Database.

`2022-04-01T09:00` --> 04/01/2022

Is there a way to parse it and rendering in a nicer format with Vue.js ?

## I have

```
<template v-slot:item.start_date="{ item }">
    <v-chip>
        {{ item.start_date }}
    </v-chip>
</template>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57945017/8172857

Comment: I saw the answer in that link, but I don't really want time as part of it.

Comment: I only want the day. MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Just replace `toLocaleString()` by `toLocaleDateString()`

Answer (score 2):

You could the `` method from the Date object :

```
<template v-slot:item.start_date="{ item }">
    <v-chip>
        {{new Date(item.start_date).toLocaleDateString() }}
    </v-chip>
</template>
```