# Axios data not displayed in Vuetify table

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z60Le.png)I am trying to display data(fetched from api through axios) in the vuetify table. As shown in the screenshots 23 empty rows has been loaded, without data.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="info"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
  <template v-slot:items="props">
      <td>{{ props.items.bugnum }}</td>
       <td>{{ props.items.dev }}</td>
       <td>{{ props.items.sev }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.items.status }}</td>
       <td>{{ props.items.sub }}</td>
     </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
      {text: 'BUG NUMBER', value: 'bugnum'},
      {text: 'DEVELOPER', value: 'dev'},
      {text: 'SEVERITY', value: 'sev'},
      {text: 'STATUS', value: 'status'},
      {text: 'SUBJECT', value: 'sub'},
      ],
      info: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3000/merged/')
      .then(response => {
        this.info = response.data
      })
  }
};
</script>
```

vue: 2.6.10
vuetify: 2.2.4

Comment: A Codepen or Codesandbox example would be really helpful. Are you sure it's `props.items.bugnum` instead of `props.item.bugnum`?

Comment: Not sure, props.item.bugnum not working either. I could not find codepan example with axios.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser dev console?

Comment: please tell us what your console prints for `response.data`

Comment: No errors in dev console! I referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180521/vuetify-data-table-not-showing-data.

Comment: response.data is something like [{"BUGNUM":123,"DEV":"abc","SEV":3,"STATUS":90,"SUB":"check123"},{"BUGNUM":345,"DEV":"cde","SEV":3,"STATUS":90,"SUB":"check456"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="info"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
  <template v-slot:items="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.BUGNUM }}</td>
       <td>{{ props.item.DEV }}</td>
       <td>{{ props.item.SEV }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.STATUS }}</td>
       <td>{{ props.item.SUB }}</td>
     </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
      {text: 'BUG NUMBER', value: 'BUGNUM'},
      {text: 'DEVELOPER', value: 'DEV'},
      {text: 'SEVERITY', value: 'SEV'},
      {text: 'STATUS', value: 'STATUS'},
      {text: 'SUBJECT', value: 'SUB'},
      ],
      info: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3000/merged/')
      .then(response => {
        this.info = response.data
      })
  }
};
</script>
```

As i think your response have Uppercase keys. May be it work.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Though, as Rie mentioned in the comment changed props.items.bugnum to props.item.bugnum.